# cURL + HTTP_POST, keep getting 500 error. Has no idea?

Tags: php, ssl, post, curl, http-post

Okay, I want to make a HTTP_POST using cURL to a SSL site. I already imported the certificate to my server. This is my code:

```
$url  = "https://www.xxx.xxx";
$post = "";# all data that going to send

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0'); 

$exe  = curl_exec($ch);
$getInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($exe === false) {
    $output = "Error in sending";
    if (curl_error($ch)){
        $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
    }
} else if($getInfo['http_code'] != 777){
    $output = "No data returned. Error: " . $getInfo['http_code'];
    if (curl_error($ch)){
        $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

It keep returned "500". Based on w3schools, 500 means Internal Server Error. Is my server having problem? How to solve/troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 8):

Some servers (especially requested with SSL) returns 500 in cases when some parameters of request is set incorrect.

To avoid «**500 error**» (for example) be sure to:

- set proper "Referer: " header if needed, with

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://site.com/ref_page');`

- set proper "User-Agent: " header, with

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');`

Answer (score 2):

```
$url  = "https://www.xxx.xxx";
$post = "";# all data that going to send

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT    5.0'); 

$exe  = curl_exec($ch);
$getInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($exe === false) {
$output = "Error in sending";
if (curl_error($ch)){
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
}
} else if($getInfo['http_code'] != 777){
$output = "No data returned. Error: " . $getInfo['http_code'];//as preline
if (curl_error($ch)){
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
}
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

BTW:
Make sure that CURL moduel is installed.

Comment: Sorry. Some typo mistakes. I was editing the code. I checked the code, the variable name is correct, it still gives me "Error: 500". Any idea? (i will edit my question, to avoid, confusion, thanks)

Comment: Then could it be, server problems? What is that 500 means? I still cant get through, keep return 500. Argggghhh!!!!

Comment: probably CURL moduel hasn't been installed yet in your server.

Comment: Hi SpawnCxy, the cURL module is installed. I was able to send to non-SSL site, using similar codes. Not sure if its about the SSL thingy

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong inside your server or the script executed on the server which, maybe, throw an unhandled exception.

You should check the server's access and error logs.

Comment: Do you mean, I should contact my hosting company?

Comment: If you don't have direct access to server's logs, you may ask them to send them to you, yes.